# Pentaho 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ReportDataFactoryException: Failed at query:

Tags: mysql, jdbc, pentaho

I have recently installed Pentaho according to the manual. I have set up a simple database `survey` and run a simple query, Query1 `SELECT * FROM 'surveys'` from JDBC (MySQL). When I preview it from JDBC Data Source, the query runs fine and shows the desired result.

But when I open the Pentaho Report Designer page and click on the Query1, it throws the following exception;

`ERROR: The query 'Query 1' did not execute successfully. The reason given was: 'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ReportDataFactoryException: Failed at query: SELECT * FROM 'surveys'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the issue. The problem was that the query was without limits. Pentaho needs Limit in queries. When I changed the above query to

`SELECT * FROM surveys LIMIT 1`

it worked. Hope this helps others.

There might be other factors which generate the above error, but in this case, it was due to the query.

Comment: It can't be the answer. Sometimes you don't know how many rows your query is going to return, so can't be putting limits on all of your queries.

Answer (score 3):

It may be a bit too late but I'm thinking it might help others. I've been facing this issue many times and every time I forget how do I solve it. Probably it would be better to write it down here and at the same time could help others too.

The reason behind this is the version of the MySQL Connector in the lib/jdbc folder. I used mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar and it caused this issue. It only works after I change it to mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar.

Comment: Worked for me. I was using 5.1.11 connector and changed to 5.1.34. Now the error has gone.

Comment: i did the same but i still have the same error though